# How can I generate OperationContract(Action, ReplyAction) in ChannelFactory automatically for a WCF service in C#?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api, channelfactory

I am working on a dashboard monitoring application. It's a REST API application using .Net Core 6.0 (C#) As part of this project, I need to monitor the activity of several web applications. Most of these applications are WCF services.

Requirements:

- I need to ping the application to check if it responds and retrieve the version (here is a HelloWorld() and GetVersion() method on all services)
- create a connection to the application 100% automatically: the only thing I have is the application name and the WSDL address (exemple :* http://namespace/WCFServiceName.svc*)

To create this connection I use ChannelFactory which establishes a connection to the application, but I can't manage to generate [OperationContract(Action="...", ReplyAction="...")] in an automatic way. To make it work, I hard-coded this information.

```
        public async Task<string> GetStatus(string serviceAddress)
        {
            BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

            myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;

            myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
            myBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Ntlm;

            EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(serviceAddress);

            ChannelFactory<IWcfService> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IWcfService>(myBinding, myEndpoint);

            // Create a channel
            IWcfService wcfClient = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
            string status = await wcfClient.HelloWorld();
            ((IClientChannel)wcfClient).Close();
            return status;
        }
```

And this is my interface **IWcfService**:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWcfService
    {
        [OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/WcfServiceName/GetVersion", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/WcfServiceName/GetVersionResponse")]
        Task<string> GetVersion();

        [OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/WcfServiceName/HelloWorld", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/WcfServiceName/HelloWorldResponse")]
        Task<string> HelloWorld();
    }
```

My goal is to get rid of this information displayed in OperationContract and generate it automatically,
for example :

```
[OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/" + **serviceName **+ "/HelloWorld", 
                   ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/" + **serviceName **+ "/HelloWorldResponse")]
```

In this case I will pass the serviceName and connect directly to any service.

Comment: Have you tried using `Add Service Reference` in Visual Studio instead of writing everything yourself? Automatic generation is already available, from the SOAP service's WSDL and XSD schemas

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I tried. The problem is that I don't know what service WCF will need to monitor in the future. Since it is a monitoring application, I need to add different applications as it is necessary without going through Visual Studio each time.

Comment: In that case inspect the SOAP payload sent from the WCF proxy and send the same, changing only the namespaces. WCF is a framework for creating SOAP services. The actual payload is an XML SOAP message sent through an HTTP POST. The Channels, contracts etc make sense when you actually want to generate a client from the schema and have it manage security, session and other SOAP features. If all you need is to send a canned request and get back a fixed response, you don't need a full client

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could you post an example please to help me visualize what you explained? In this case, do I have to use HttpClient to make a GET request to service?

Comment: Maybe the methods **BeforeSendReply** in [IDispatchMessageInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) will help you. It allows you to modify inbound and outbound application messages.